# MVC approach for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, puremvc, robotlegs

I am searching for a decent framework for organizing my Javascript, **jQuery** assisted code according to MVCS micro-architecture.

I did some research on [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com), and though it looks like a robust product, I'm afraid it's a bit of an "overkill" for my needs, and since it's poorly documented it will take me hours to exclude only the parts of it that I can utilize.

What I really search for is something elegant like a jQuery-[PureMVC](http://puremvc.org/) port (which as far as I know does not exist) or [Robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/) (for those who are familiar with this AS3 framework). 
In other words: I look for a light and simple framework that will allow me to easily manage the business logic surrounding my many existing custom **jQuery UI Widgets**.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Are you making a primarily javascript application, or do you just use javascript for front end stuff like client side validation and fancy UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)

> Backbone supplies structure to
>   JavaScript-heavy applications by
>   providing models with key-value
>   binding and custom events, collections
>   with a rich API of enumerable
>   functions, views with declarative
>   event handling, and connects it all to
>   your existing application over a
>   RESTful JSON interface.

It's lightweight and allows you to plugin into the abstractions easily. It was also designed to not have a UI attached to it so you can plug in jQuery or whatever other library you intend to use.

Comment: Looks like what I've been looking for, 10x.

Comment: i use backbone for everything i do. +1

Answer (score 0):

Have a quick look at [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/), a companion project to [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/).

It is a fairly small but powerful framework, which lets you build things from the ground up.

Here a brief tutorial on [how to develop a single page app with Backbone.js](http://andyet.net/blog/2010/oct/29/building-a-single-page-app-with-backbonejs-undersc/).